# How to generate alert on button click in symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to generate an alert ('hi') when the user clicks on a button in symfony. If anybody knows the solution then please help.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to do this unobtrusively. Give your button a `class` or `id`, and then reference this from JavaScript.

```
$builder->add('save', ButtonType::class, array(
    'attr' => array('class' => 'save', 'id' => 'myBtn'),
));
```

And then in your template, beneath the form:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function() { alert('hi'); });
</script>
```

Comment: my button is like this {% block formButtons %}
    {% trans "Save Order" %}, XiboTimelineSaveOrder("timelineControl")
{% endblock %}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
$form = $builder->getForm();
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
    $this->addFlash("success", "hi");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution is to use jquery ..
in your formType add this:

```
$builder->add('ADD', ButtonType::class, array(
'attr' => array('class' => 'add', 'id' => 'myBtn'),
```

));

in js after add cdn jquery add this code:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function{ alert('here');});
```